# Swift UI(Xcode 12 Beta): Failed to built ContentView.swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I tried to write my first app with Swift UI but I failed at updating preview and the simulator still worked, couldn't figure out why. I've searched for solutions like
`sudo xcodebuild -license`
and assigning the Command Line Tools to Xcode 12 Beta, which didn't work at all. Sorry for my bad English.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON2O2.png)

Comment: Press the info button and see what is wrong.

Comment: updated with a new screenshot, thx for telling

Comment: Did you name your project `try`? If so I would suggest naming your project something else, as try is a reserved word.

Comment: Andrew's suggestion fixed this problem! Thank you all for helping me. QAQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to replicate the issue you had and it seems that the project name is the problem. As [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5508175/andrew) mentioned in the comments, `try` is a reserved keyword in Swift. Choose a better name for your project and everything will work correctly.